# Receiving unexpected content in http response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm working through the Python Challenge in an effort to learn Python. Throughout these challenges grabbing the page source can be very beneficial. However, I am not receiving the page source that I'm expecting when using the Python-Requests package on my Windows machine.

The code:

```
# Using requests
import requests
url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

My response (formatted for readability):

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</head>
<body>
<script>
*Copyright (c) 2010 John Resig, http://jquery.com/
*Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaininga copy
*of this software and associated documentation files //(the"Software"), to deal
*in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
* use, copy, modify,\tmerge, //publish,distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies
*of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
*subject //to the following conditions: The above copyright notice and this permission        notice shall be included in a
*ll copies or substantial portions of the Software.

var keyString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012
3456789+/=";
function uTF8Encode(string) 
{
string = string.replace(/x0dx0a/g, "x0a");
var output = "";
for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
if (c < 128) {
output += String.fromCharCode(c);
else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
output += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
output += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
else {
output += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
output += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
output += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
}
}
return output;
}

function base64Encode(input)
{
var output = "";
var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
var i = 0;
input = uTF8Encode(input);
while (i < input.length) {
chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
enc4 = chr3 & 63;
if (isNaN(chr2)) {
enc3 = enc4 = 64;
} 
else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
enc4 = 64;
}
output = output + keyString.charAt(enc1) + keyString.charAt(enc2) + keyString.charAt(enc3) + keyString.charAt(enc4);
}
return output;
}
window.top.location.href = 'https://205.159.94.140/connect/Access?AgentCode=000&url=' + base64Encode(window.top.location.href) + '&cti=';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page in question: http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html

The response I'm getting does not match the source I receive when I check with my browser. Also, when I run my code on my other machine (OS X) I can grab the page source just fine. Why is this occurring?

Comment: First, to rule some simple stuff out: Are you using the same versions of Python and requests on the two machines? If you run the script on Windows a few times, does it get the wrong thing every time?

Comment: works fine on linux also, are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: How are you invoking the script on Windows? Are both computers on the same network? Looks like the Windows machine is making a request through a proxy or a wifi network that requires you to officially join the network through (e.g.) a popup.

Comment: try to do it in a python shell in cmd

Comment: @mjk This might be the issue. The Windows machine is though my workplace network while the other was from home. Same version of Python (3.4). Using Python Tools for Visual Studio to run.

Comment: @PapaJohn You'll see at the bottom of your response is a forwarding request to what looks like a typical wifi network auth screen. I presume if you just open a web browser on that computer you get the same thing? Or is it session based?

Comment: @mjk I can open new browser windows and my home page opens up without issue. I looked into my browser network settings, looks like the browser is using my system's settings to connect, and that includes a proxy configuration script found under LAN settings. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @PapaJohn Quite possibly! You can actually use a proxy with the `requests` library -- check out http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies. Presuming it's just using HTTP basic authentication, you can just pass a proxies definition object. I'll write a simple answer to explain since the comment formatting isn't great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a different response because your request is being routed to a proxy on your Windows box's (different) local network (note the redirect at the bottom: `window.top.location.href = 'https://205.159.94.140/connect/Access?AgentCode=000...`).

You can pass the proxy's network configuration to your `requests.get()` call to prevent the redirect. From [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://user:pass@205.159.94.140",
  "https": "http://user:pass@205.159.94.140"
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Per your comments, the actual proxy IP address and auth information should be found in your LAN settings.

Comment: Thank you so much @mjk. Found the proxy IP in the script linked to my LAN settings, passed the proxy to reqests.get(), and I could read the page source without issue!